# add class on active div using jquery

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshmonster/b3VaX/2/). I want to add class on current active div. I know i need to use addClass() but i don't know where i have to use that ?

html:

```
<div class="myclass selected">
Content 1
</div>
<div class="myclass">
    Content 2
</div>
<div class="myclass">
Content 3
</div>

<ul>
  <li><img     src="http://www.lillehammer.com/ImageVault/Images/id_2122/scope_66/ImageVaultHandler.aspx"     /></li>
  <li><img     src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Valued_image_seal.svg/40px-            Valued_image_seal.svg.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.iconico.com/i/icoImageFilterPro100.gif" /></li>
</ul>

<a class="next">next</a>
```

jquery:

```
$('img', 'ul').on('click', function() {
    $(".myclass").eq($(this).parent('li').index()).show()
                 .siblings('div').hide();
});

$('.selected').show();

$(".next").click(function(){
    if ($('.myclass:visible').length) {
        var curr = $('.myclass:visible'),
            next = curr.next('.myclass').length?    curr.next('.myclass'):$('.myclass').first();

        curr.hide();
        next.show();
    }else{
        $('.myclass').first().show();
    }
});
```

​
​

Answer (score 3):

Is your intention to highlight the `li` that is currently active? http://jsfiddle.net/b3VaX/50/

Your code is fine, but if your css focus's on highlighting and display, your javascript can just worry about toggling the css class for the active elements.

```
setActive(0);

$('li').click(function() {
    setActive($(this).index());
});

$(".next").click(function(){
    var current = $('ul li.selected').index(),
        maxIndex = $('ul li').length - 1,
        next = (current + 1) >  maxIndex ? 0 : (current + 1);

    setActive(next);
});

function setActive(i) {
    var li = $('ul li').eq(i);

    $('ul li').removeClass('selected');
    li.addClass('selected');
    $('.myclass').removeClass('selected');
    $('.myclass').eq(i).addClass('selected');
}

​
```

css:

```
.myclass.selected {
    display: block;
}

ul li.selected {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure where you actually want to add / remove the classes, but have a look:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    if ($('.myclass:visible').length) {
        var curr = $('.myclass:visible'),
            next = curr.next('.myclass').length?curr.next('.myclass'):$('.myclass').first();

        curr.hide().removeClass('someClassHere');
        next.show().addClass('someOtherClassHere');
    }else{
        $('.myclass').first().show();
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3VaX/6/)

Comment: i want to add .active class on ul img that which is active.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to add a class to the element you're showing and remove it from the element you're hiding. This should do exactly that: http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/b3VaX/15/

The changes I made are quite simple: in each of your click events, when you show() something, the 'selected' class is added, and when you hide() something, it's removed.

Comment: i need it on img to add class.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want to do
http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/b3VaX/39/

css:

```
li.active img{border:1px solid red}
```

at first, 'activate' the first li,

```
$('ul#myul li:first').addClass('active');
```

then on click activate the next:

```
$('ul#myul li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active').length ||
$('ul#myul li:first').addClass('active');
```

Comment: if i want to update even i click img means what i have to do ?

Comment: i don't get your question! sorry